# How to use barplot() to get two variables side by side?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, bar-chart

My data frame is number of gifts for boys and number of gifts for girls according to each state.

I'm trying to plot two variables side by side using the `barplot()` function.

I can't figure out how to get both on there, the way I'm doing it now is that it's assigning two colours but to the same parameter.

Essentially what I want to do is assign two bars for each region (so for New Hampshire it plots `df$GB` `df$GG`, Mass it plots `df$GB` and `df$GG`, etc...)

Any thoughts?

```
y <- as.matrix(df$GB, df$GG)

barplot(y, main='Gifts', col=c('green', 'red'), 
        beside=TRUE, legend=c('G', 'H'), xaxt='n')

axis(1, at=1: nrow(df), labels=df$Region, las=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that as input `barplot` likes matrices (or vectors), where the columns represent the units, and the rows the groups.

So you were close and just not successful in creating the needed matrix yet. Note, that in `as.<something>` we always put in just *one* object, while you put *two* columns extra. You want a subset of the data frame `as.matrix(df[c('GB', 'GG')])`. You also want to `t`ranspose it, `t(as.matrix(df[c('GB', 'GG')]))`, where `t(df[c('GB', 'GG')])` is sufficient since `t` automatically coerces to a matrix.

`barplot()` is rich in arguments, it's definitely worth to read `?barplot` on what is possible. E.g. you may specify additional arguments for the legend with a list in `args.legend` (read `'?legend` for options) and define a `names.arg` for the x-axis labels. For the latter I'd use a named vector `nm` that assigns abbreviations to the regions, the explanation can be put into the description below the graphic. (In this case this might be a better idea than rotating long labels, even though it's nice to know how to do it, see at the bottom of my answer, though.)

```
(nm <- setNames(c("CT", "ME", "MA", "NH", "RI", "VT"), df$region))
# Connecticut         Maine Massachusetts New Hampshire  Rhode Island       Vermont 
#        "CT"          "ME"          "MA"          "NH"          "RI"          "VT"
```

So we could the `barplot` like so.

```
barplot(t(df[c('GB', 'GG')]), main='Gifts', col=c('green', 'red'), 
        beside=TRUE, legend.text=c('Girls', 'Boys'), 
        names.arg=nm[df$region], ylim=c(0, max(df[c('GB', 'GG')]) + 1),
        args.legend=list(title='Sex', cex=.9))
```

[image]

If you rely on the long names, notice that `barplot` invisibly outputs the midpoints of the bars, which can be used for label positioning. You can also extend the `mar` of axis 1 a little.

```
op <- par(mar=c(6, 4, 4, 2))  ## set par

b <- barplot(t(df[c('GB', 'GG')]), beside=TRUE)
axis(side=1, at=colMeans(b), labels=df$region, las=2)

par(op)  ## restore old par
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(GB = c(6L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 1L), GG = c(8L, 5L, 
4L, 10L, 2L, 6L), region = c("Connecticut", "Maine", "Massachusetts", 
"New Hampshire", "Rhode Island", "Vermont")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Incredibly detailed and educational, thanks so much for spending time on this!

Answer (score 1):

You will get a faster response with code adapted to your data if you provide a reproducible sample using something like `dput(head(df, 5))`. Without that I'll provide some data that may resemble yours:

```
df <- structure(list(Region = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), GB = c(1L, 
5L, 10L, 8L, 2L), GG = c(4L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Now the boxplot:

```
barplot(t(df[, 2:3]), beside=TRUE, names=df$Region)
legend("topleft", c("Girls", "Boys"), fill=c("black", "gray"))
```

[image: Barplot]